# DataTables using Export Buttons and YADCF causes select lists to be exported

Tags: coldfusion, datatables, yadcf

Is there a way to use the export buttons and yadcf chozen filter together without messing up the column headers in the export see below the column Order Number has Select appended

Order NumberSelect
value20766903232802532374885123748865237490732374944323749625x

**Code:**

```
<!doctype html>
```

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/newwebadmin/mvc/orders/assets/css/cancellationStatistics.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/newwebadmin/js/chosen/chosen.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/yadcf/0.9.1/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.css">
    <script src="/newwebadmin/mvc/orders/assets/js/cancellations/ChartNew.js"></script>
    <script src="/newwebadmin/mvc/orders/assets/js/cancellations/shapesInChart.js"></script>
    <script src="/newwebadmin/mvc/orders/assets/js/cancellations/specialInChartData.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.27/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.27/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/newwebadmin/js/Chosen/chosen.jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/yadcf/0.9.1/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        input[type="search"] {
            border:1px #cccccc solid;
            padding:2px;
            border-radius: 2px;

        }
    </style>        
    <title>Cancel Order Reportle></title>
</head>


<cfset local.getCancellationReportData = rc.cancellations>



<body>
    <!--- <cfdump var="#local#"> --->
    <cfoutput>
        <div class="flexbox-container">

            <div class="main-content clearfix">
                <div class="container">
                    <form action="" method="post">
                        <label for="startDate">Date Range: </label>
                        <input type="text" id="startDate" name="startDate" class="button" value="#structKeyExists(form, "startDate") ? form.startDate : DateFormat(Now(),'mm/dd/yyyy') #">
                        <label for="endDate">to</label>
                        <input type="text" id="endDate" name="endDate" class="button" value="#structKeyExists(form, "endDate") ? form.endDate : DateFormat(DateAdd('m',1,Now()),'mm/dd/yyyy') #">
                        <input type="submit" id="btnFilter" value="Filter" class="button">
                    </form>
                    <br><br>
                    <button id="platinum" class="button">Show Platinum Customers</button>
                    <button id="nonplatinum" class="button">Show Non-Platinum Customers</button>
                    <button id="all" class="button">Show All</button>

                    <br><br>
                    <table id="report" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <thead>
                                <th align="left">Order Number</th>
                                <th align="left">VendorID</th>
                                <th align="left">User Index</th>
                                <th align="left">Customer Type</th>
                                <th align="left">Date</th>
                                <th align="left">## of items cancelled</th>
                                <th align="left">Total$</th>
                                <th align="left">Canceled By</th>
                                <th align="left">Reason</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <th colspan="5" style="text-align:right">Total:</th>
                                <th style="text-align:left"></th>
                                <th colspan="2" style="text-align:left"></th>
                                <th></th>


                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                        <tbody>
                            <cfloop query="local.getCancellationReportData">
                                <tr data-isPlatinum="#is_platinum#">
                                    <td>#order_number#</td>
                                    <td>#len(vendorID) ? vendorID: 'unknown'#</td>
                                    <td>#len(dbo_tblEmployee_ID) ? dbo_tblEmployee_ID: 'unknown'#</td>
                                    <td>#customerType#</td>
                                    <td>#DateFormat(date,'mm/dd/yyyy')# #timeFormat(date,'hh:mm TT')#</td>
                                    <td>#qty#</td>
                                    <td align="right">#DollarFOrmat(ExtendedCost)#</td>
                                    <td>#cancelledBy#</td>
                                    <td>#cancellation_reason#</td>

                                </tr>
                            </cfloop>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </cfoutput>


    <script>


            $(document).ready(function() {
                var table = $('#report').DataTable( {
                    dom: 'Bfrtip',
                    buttons: [
                        {extend :'excel', text:'Export to Excel'}
                       ,{extend :'pdf'  , text:'Export to PDF', orientation: 'landscape', pageSize: 'LEGAL'}
                        ,'print'
                    ],

                    "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
                                var api = this.api(), data;

                                // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
                                var intVal = function ( i ) {
                                    return typeof i === 'string' ?
                                        i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 :
                                        typeof i === 'number' ?
                                            i : 0;
                                };

                                // Total over all pages
                                total = api
                                    .column( 6 )
                                    .data()
                                    .reduce( function (a, b) {
                                        return intVal(intVal(a) + intVal(b)).toFixed(2);
                                    } );

                                // Total over this page
                                pageTotal = api
                                    .column( 6, { page: 'current'} )
                                    .data()
                                    .reduce( function (a, b) {
                                        return intVal(intVal(a) + intVal(b)).toFixed(2);
                                    }, 0 );

                                // Total over all pages
                                cantotal = api
                                    .column( 5 )
                                    .data()
                                    .reduce( function (a, b) {
                                        return intVal(intVal(a) + intVal(b));
                                    } );

                                // Total over this page
                                canpageTotal = api
                                    .column( 5, { page: 'current'} )
                                    .data()
                                    .reduce( function (a, b) {
                                        return intVal(intVal(a) + intVal(b));
                                    }, 0 );



                                // Update footer
                                $( api.column( 6 ).footer() ).html(
                                    '$'+pageTotal +' ( $'+ total +' total )'
                                );
                                 // Update footer
                                $( api.column( 5 ).footer() ).html(
                                    ''+canpageTotal +' ( out of '+ cantotal +')'
                                );
                            }






                });

                $("#platinum").click(function() {
                     $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();
                    table.draw();
                    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
                      function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
                          return $(table.row(dataIndex).node()).attr('data-isPlatinum') == 1;
                        }
                    );
                    table.draw();
                });

                $("#nonplatinum").click(function() {
                    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();
                    table.draw();
                    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
                      function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
                          return $(table.row(dataIndex).node()).attr('data-isPlatinum') == 0;
                        }
                    );
                    table.draw();
                });

                $("#all").click(function() {
                    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();
                    table.draw();
                });

                $('.button').button();

                var dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy",
                  from = $( "#startDate" )
                    .datepicker({
                      defaultDate: "+1w",
                      changeMonth: true,
                      numberOfMonths: 3
                    })
                    .on( "change", function() {
                      to.datepicker( "option", "minDate", getDate( this ) );
                    }),
                  to = $( "#endDate" ).datepicker({
                    defaultDate: "+1w",
                    changeMonth: true,
                    numberOfMonths: 3
                  })
                  .on( "change", function() {
                    from.datepicker( "option", "maxDate", getDate( this ) );
                  });

                function getDate( element ) {
                  var date;
                  try {
                    date = $.datepicker.parseDate( dateFormat, element.value );
                  } catch( error ) {
                    date = null;
                  }

                  return date;
                };


                yadcf.init(table, [
                    {column_number : 0},
                    {column_number : 1, filter_type: "multi_select",select_type: 'chosen'},
                    {column_number : 2},
                    {column_number : 3},
                    {column_number : 4},
                    {column_number : 5},
                    {column_number : 6},
                    {column_number : 7},
                    {column_number : 8},
                    {column_number : 9}
                    ]);


            });

    </script>
```

I have tied this

```
buttons: [
                        {extend :'excel', text:'Export to Excel'}
                       ,{extend :'pdf'  , text:'Export to PDF', orientation: 'landscape', pageSize: 'LEGAL'
                            ,exportOptions:{
                                rows: ':not(.notPrintable)'
                                }
                        }
                        ,'print'
                    ],
```

...

```
yadcf.init(table, [
                    {column_number : 0},
                    {column_number : 1, filter_type: "multi_select",select_type: 'chosen'},
                    {column_number : 2},
                    {column_number : 3},
                    {column_number : 4},
                    {column_number : 5},
                    {column_number : 6},
                    {column_number : 7},
                    {column_number : 8}

                    ]);

                $(".yadcf-filter-wrapper").addClass("notPrintable");
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me

```
buttons: [
                        {extend :'excel', text:'Export to Excel'
                            ,exportOptions: {
                                format: {
                                    header: function ( data, row, column, node ) {
                                        var newdata = data;

                                        newdata = newdata.replace(/<.*?<\/*?>/gi, '');
                                        newdata = newdata.replace(/<div.*?<\/div>/gi, '');
                                        newdata = newdata.replace(/<\/div.*?<\/div>/gi, '');
                                        return newdata;
                                    }
                                }

                            }

                    }
                       ,{extend :'pdf'  , text:'Export to PDF'
                            ,exportOptions: {
                                format: {
                                    header: function ( data, row, column, node ) {
                                        var newdata = data;

                                        newdata = newdata.replace(/<.*?<\/*?>/gi, '');
                                        newdata = newdata.replace(/<div.*?<\/div>/gi, '');
                                        newdata = newdata.replace(/<\/div.*?<\/div>/gi, '');
                                        return newdata;
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                        }
                        ,{extend :'print'  , text:'Print'
                            ,exportOptions: {
                                format: {
                                    header: function ( data, row, column, node ) {
                                        var newdata = data;

                                        newdata = newdata.replace(/<.*?<\/*?>/gi, '');
                                        newdata = newdata.replace(/<div.*?<\/div>/gi, '');
                                        newdata = newdata.replace(/<\/div.*?<\/div>/gi, '');
                                        return newdata;
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    ],
```

Comment: This was very helpful.  To handle additional yadcf types I also had to add in these lines (probably could rewrite the regex to be more generic, but it works for now).  

newdata = newdata.replace(/<button.*?<\/div>/gi, '');
newdata = newdata.replace(/<span.*?<\/span>/gi, '');
newdata = newdata.replace(/<span.*?<\/div>/gi, '');